# Git SVN error on OS X El Capitan

Tags: git, perl, svn, osx-elcapitan

I am using SourceTree application and when i fetch from svn i take this error message. How can i solve this problem.

```
Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2 /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/lib/perl5/site_perl /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 25.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the SVN::Core module?

Comment: sudo mkdir /Library/Perl/5.18/auto;

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level;

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN /Library/Perl/5.18/auto/